# Session cookie - Servername info - can it be done in the application code

Tags: java, session-cookies

Scenario:
2 managed servers in a cluster. Application is deployed on the cluster.

Requirement:
Application needs to send a cookie to the user with server info.

Question is regarding session cookies. Can the application retrieve the server name (for example ManagedServer1) from which that request has been processed and send to the user in the cookie.?

Request->process->Response with cookie containig the server name it was process by.

Can it be done in the application code?

/SR

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see [request.getServerName()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName%28%29).